# invoke another macro in struct define

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I made a simple macro that defines a struct.

```rust
macro_rules! __body {
  ($($body:tt)+) => {
    $($body)+
  };
}

macro_rules! new_struct {
  ($(#[$attr:meta])* struct $name:ident { $($body:tt)+ } ) => {
    $(#[$attr])* struct $name {
      __body!($($body)+);
    }
  };
}

new_struct! {
  #[derive(Deserialize)]
  struct Test {
    a: bool,
    b: String,
  }
}
```

When I compile this code, it raises an error:

```
   |
14 |         __body!($($body)+);
   |               ^ expected `:`
...
19 | / new_struct! {
20 | |   #[derive(Deserialize)]
21 | |   struct Test {
22 | |     a: bool,
23 | |     b: String,
24 | |   }
25 | | }
   | |_- in this macro invocation
   |
```

Comment: If you just use the `$body` tokens directly, rather than pass them to another macro, this will work fine. ie `$($body)+` instead of `__body!($($body)+);`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html):

> Macros can expand to expressions, statements, items (including traits, impls, and foreign items), types, or patterns.

and struct fields are none of these, so you cannot use a declarative macro for that. You may want to try [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) instead.